# what tools would a sapient parrot use?

Tags: avian

In a world where birds have become sapient, what tool would a sapient parrot use?

These parrots have discovered metalworking and can forge metal. They are not humanoid and still need to fly.

They where forced to evolve in intelligence due to poachers. When humans went extinct, they kept the sapience to survive and successfully ward off enemies.
They need their weapons to defend towns and eggs.

Comment: Tools to do what? You're going as broad as asking what tools a man can use, which makes it kind of hard to answer. Focus on a recurring theme you'd like to see in your world/story, or perhaps on a difficult topic for you. Either way, you'll be able to see patterns you can reuse in other domains of activity, with some specifics here and there :).

Comment: On another note, when you say "still need to fly", you simply mean that they're like real-world parrots, only much more clever (though they're not that silly in the first place ^^)?

Comment: @loutubeandfriends, please add that info to the question, don't add it as a comment

Comment: *Rich* sapient parrots won't use any tools, because they can simply give orders to their human and psittacine servants. *Poor* parrots will use the tools they are told to use by their betters. (And, please make a note that the sense "metalworking" for the word *forgery* has been obsolete for some three centuries. The meaning first shifted to "fictional invention", and then since the 18th century the word only means "fraudulent fabrication (of a document)". You probably wanted to say metalworking or forging, I cannot tell which. Note that forging is but one of many kinds of metalworking.)

Comment: *These parrots have discovered metalworking and can forge metal.* So what tools does that require ?  Your problem is that parrots are somewhat challenged anatomically compared to humans.  Hard to see how a parrot operating a hammer makes much sense.  No arms, no thumbs, no hands.  And hard to see them apply much leverage.

Comment: @StephenG Do a youtube search for Gumi and then watch the videos where he takes toy video games in his claws and beats his perch with them, before throwing them down. Give him some sentience and the throws could very well be aimed....

Answer (score 1):

"Habilis" birds would be challenged by the lack of hands/arms and would need to compensate for that.

1. **Beak tools**. Beak is the most agile and precise "limb" of a bird. Some birds already know to use object held in their beak to perform different tasks. So, for the smart birds, first tools would be held in a beak, not leg.
2. **Secure seats/cradles**. This is not exactly a tool, but it would be instrumental in letting birds keep both of their legs free.